# Oracle does full table scan in like '%test% query

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I have a table with millions of entries in it. There are also some indices for the three fields `city`, `street` and `name`.

But when i perform the following query, it takes 10 seconds+ to return any result.

```
SELECT bd.*
FROM BASEDATA bd 
WHERE 1=1 
AND lower(city) LIKE '%city%' 
AND lower(street) LIKE '%street%' 
AND lower(name) LIKE '%schmidt%'
```

When looking at the explain plan, it shows the the query is executed with a full table scan instead of using the indices .

Comment: And the question is? (Yes, this is how it works, those LIKEs can't use indices.)

Comment: Oracle can not use an index for such a LIKE condition.

Comment: Oracle *can* use an index but it's not necessarily going to be faster than a full table scan.

Answer (score 5):

Basically an index organises values in an alphanumeric order. Given a predicate it looks up the index starting from the leading edge of the value. So for `key = 'ABC'` it goes to the part of the index with values starting with `A` and searches from there.

Now we look at your query and we see that none of the predicates in your WHERE clause have leading values. `lower(city) LIKE '%city%'` can literally match anything from `aaa city`  to `zzz city`. So potentially every record in the table. An index is useless in such a scenario, and a full table scan is way more efficient.

(Incidentally, applying a function to a column, as in `lower(city)` would also prevent the use of an index, unless you have the appropriate function-based index on that column.)

If you want to do lots of this sort of querying you should investigate Oracle's Text functionality. It uses special indexes to support free text operators like `contains()`. There are overheads for these indexes, so you need to understand what benefits you will get. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCAPP/toc.htm).

Comment: It looks like you are building your query dynamically in some app?  Perhaps you could disallow the use of a leading %, as Oracle can use an index in that case.

Comment: Technically, a full table scan could be replaced with a full index scan which *might* give a performance boost if it's a covering index and the query terms are very selective.